# how to use Imageview as Clickable?

Tags: android, imageview

How can I use imageview as a button(clickable) in my project? As of now i am using button object but i want to display an image and not a button.

Thanks in advance

## android

Comment: hi bro Ragu !Can you please google it these things? there is lot of answers available there regards your question. If you post question similar this, you may get downvote !

Answer (score 2):

ImageView do listen to click events i.e. OnClickListener. So if you plan to use them as clickable you do not need any additional set up for it.

Simply create an ImageView,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgClickable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="your image"
/>
```

Then get its reference in your Java code,

```
 ImageView clikableImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgClickable);
 clikableImage .setOnClickListener(this); //This make it clickable
```

And finally handle its onClick event by overriding

```
@override
public void onClick(View v){
    //Your action
}
```

Comment: And, you can also consider ImageButton's. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:clickable="true" attribute. And then you can use onClickListener to implement a listener.

But if you want to use an image instead of button you should consider ImageButton. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Either in your layout when you define the `ImageView` you can add `android:onClick="someFunction"` and which calls `someFunction` whenever you click the image (make sure you define it in your code) or you can programmatically just add an `onClickListener` to the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the ImageView wherever you want on your layout and implement the OnClickListener interface to listen for click events. It would be something like:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
imager.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wll how about using ImageButton.

Uoc can find it when you open a layout xml file, and at the Grapichal layout - You would see ImageButton unter the Images&Media options menu.